# Get client hostname in Guacamole RDP session

Tags: guacamole

We're using Guacamole for RDP sessions, but as we have several workstations located around the city.  Each time a user connects it returns:

```
ClientAddress: 10.0.0.1XX (Guacamole Server IP)
ClientName: Guacamole RDP
```

I need to know if there's a way for each connection to give me the IP and the real name of the workstation that connects through Guac.

**E.x.** Instead of `10.0.0.190` I need `192.168.1.XX` and the ClientName TAG10 (every workstation has its own hostname.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guacamole version 1.0.0 and above, you will need to configure `RemoteIpValve` in your tomcat in order to see the source IP.

Firstly, make sure that your proxy send `X-Forwarded-For` header. For example (in nginx):

```
location /guacamole/ {
    proxy_pass http://HOSTNAME:8080/guacamole/;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    access_log off;
}
```

Next, configure `RemoteIpValve` in tomcat. It is used to pass through remote IP address to the application.

Go to tomcat `conf` directory, and edit this file (`conf/server.xml`). Under the `<Host>` section, add the following:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
               internalProxies="127.0.0.1"
               remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
               remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
               protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

For more info, you may refer to here:
[Guacamole - Hostname logging within database](http://guacamole.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/#hostname-logging-within-database)